# Clip a video texture into two

Tags: three.js, glsl

I have a video texture which i have to clip into 2 parts ie, the size of the texture is 1920 * 1080, I have to clip this video texture to 1920 * 540 and the remaining to another texture and input those into two different shaders. I'm not sure whether I should use shaders or threejs for clipping. How can I clip this video texture?

Comment: Have a look at this official example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same texture on two plane models, but change the UV coordinates of the planes to display whatever part of the texture you want.

Basically get the geometry of the plane, loop through its faceVertexUVs and multiply the x of each by 0.5, and on the second object, add 0.5 to the x as well.

The first plane will short the left half of the video and the right face will show the right half.

A potentially less efficient but maybe workable solution is the .clone() the video texture.. set its .offset and .scale to shift the mapping to where you want... and apply the first texture to a mat on the left plane, and the second on the right half... but I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: what if i should clip a texture of height 1502 to 1000 and 502. Can I clip the texture precisely in these type of scenarios ?

Comment: Yeah you can scale the UVs to any arbitrary section of the image you want to display. It doesn't even have to be square :D